# Is it proper to refer to a clothes dryer as a drying machine?

Tags: synonyms, dialects

A clothes washing machine is commonly referred to as either a "washer" or a "washing machine" but I have only ever heard of a clothes dryer being referred to as a "dryer". Is it a regional thing? Is "washing machine" preferred over "washer"? Is there anyone who does use the term "drying machine"? I am from Chicago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I consider "washer" and "washing machine" to be interchangeable. Same with "dryer" and "clothes dryer". Never heard "clothes washer" or "drying machine". No idea why they don't line up, but I expect if we plot the history of the various appliances it will make some sense. A washer would have been one of the earliest domestic appliances, followed closely by the fridge. The dryer would have come later - it's more of a convenience than a major labour-saving device.

Comment: I think the different times the products were released makes a lot of sense as the reason for the names not aligning. Thanks!